# Java Swing: how to pass mouse events through JLayeredPane

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, jlayeredpane

Can a `JLayeredPane` pass along mouse events from the top layer to a lower layer?

I have two components inside a `JLayeredPane`: one `JFrame` displaying a map, and one `JEditorPane` displaying HTML text on top of it. The `JEditorPane` is partially transparent and functions as an overlay, showing text on top of the map but being otherwise invisible.

My problem: when the mouse is moved to the transparent parts of the `JEditorPane`, the `JFrame` of the map doesn't get the mouse events.

In JavaFX, the `StackPane` component has the `setPickOnBounds(false)` to pass the mouse events to the frames underneath if the mouse if it's over a transparent pixel.

Is there something of the sort in `JLayeredPane`?

Comment: Basically I'm looking for the opposite of this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32893810/why-does-a-jbutton-under-a-jpanel-still-react

Comment: Why can't you attach your listener to the `JEditorPane`?

Comment: @Raffaele I could, but how do I then pass the event to the other layer?

Comment: Why do you need to? Can't you handle the event in that listener?

Comment: The map `JFrame` contains a lot of different components with a lot of different associated mouse events already programmed in. So it would be simpler and less error prone to just forward the events to the correct layer instead of refactoring the whole program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass a mouse event `e` to a component `c`, use

```java
    c.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(e.getComponent(), e, c));
```

For example, to pass a mouse click event from `b` to `c`, use

```java
b.addMouseListener(
        new MouseAdapter() {
          @Override
          public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            c.dispatchEvent(SwingUtilities.convertMouseEvent(b, e, c));
          }
        });
```